# Independence/Dependence of Random variable

Tags: probability

Say that I have two independent discrete random variables $X,Y$ st

$X+Y=Z$

I think that $Z=z$ ($Z$ is constant)  makes $X$ and $Y$ dependent?

However in my notes it says that we can compute the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Z=z$ as follows:

$Pr(X=x|Z=z)\propto Pr(X=x \cap Z=z)=Pr(Y=z-x \cap X=x)=Pr(Y=z-x)Pr(X=x)$

But the last step implies that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: So... you know that Z=8 and I tell you that X=3; does this give you some information about the value of Y?

Comment: @Did I have amended my post to elaborate on my confusion.

Comment: This changes the meaning of the question completely. The sum of $X$ and $Y$ isn't actually constant, you just condition on the event $\{Z = z\}$. Note that by assumption you have the independence of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent; $X|Z=z$ and $Y|Z=z$ are not (indeed,  $(X|Z=z)+(Y|Z=z)=z$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=1$ and $Y=1$ with probability one. As random variables, $X$ and $Y$ are independent:

$$P(X=1)=1, P(X\not =1)=0, P(Y=1)=1, P(Y\not =1)=0$$
and

$$P(X=1\cap Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)=1$$
$$P(X=1\cap Y\not=1)=P(X=1)P(Y\not=1)=0$$
$$P(X\not =1\cap Y=1)=P(X\not =1)P(Y=1)=0$$
$$P(X\not=1\cap Y\not =1)=P(X\not =1)P(Y\not =1)=0.$$
At the same time

$$P(Z=X+Y=2)=1.$$

That is, $Z=X+Y=$contant does not necessarily mean that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent (not independent.)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple counterexample, suppose $X\sim\operatorname{Ber}(p)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Ber}(q)$ are independent, and $Z=X+Y$. Then
$$\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0\mid Z=1)=0 $$
while
$$\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0) = \mathbb P(X=0)\mathbb P(Y=0) = (1-p)(1-q)\ne 0. $$

Answer (score 0):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent iff they are both constant.

Assume they are both independent. Since the map $x \mapsto z - x$ is a homeomorphism, the identity $\sigma(X) = \sigma(z - Y) = \sigma(Y)$ holds. But a sigma-algebra is independent from itself iff it is $P$-trivial, that is all sets have a probability of either $0$ or $1$. But this means that $X$ and $Y$ are constant.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0,x_1$ be distinct with $P(X=x_0)$ and $P(X=x_1)$ both positive.

Then: $$P(Y=z-x_0\mid X=x_0)=1\neq0=P(Y=z-x_0\mid X=x_1)$$

This shows that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

There is one escape: $P(X=x_0)=1=P(Y=y_0)$ for some $x_0,y_0$ with $x_0+y_0=z$.

Two rv's that are both a.s. constant are independent.